# I am wondering whether we should not install SQL Server 2014 on a domain controller

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am a system administrator for a small firm. Now we consider to rollout Windows Server 2008 R2 for the firm.
We plan to implement Active Directory.
We would also like to upgrade RDMS, from SQL server 2000 to SQL Server 2014.

We can afford to buy just one server due to size of our organization, so we plan to implement both of AD and SQL Server 2014 on the same machine.
However, Microsoft recommends not to install SQL Server 2014 on a domain controller.

I have checked the reasons, but I don't understand what is the problem, so if someone answers my questions bellow, it's really helpful.

(1)You cannot run SQL Server services on a domain controller under a local service account.
→If we run SQL Server on a domain controller under a domain user account, what would happens?

(2)After SQL Server is installed on a computer, you cannot change the computer from a domain member to a domain controller.
You must uninstall SQL Server before you change the host computer to a domain controller.
→We plan to promote our server to a domain controller before installing SQL server 2014 and don't plan to de-promote to
member server because it's our only server. Is our plan wrong?

(3)After SQL Server is installed on a computer, you cannot change the computer from a domain controller to a domain member. 
You must uninstall SQL Server before you change the host computer to a domain member.
→We don't plan to de-promote to member server because it's our only server. Is our plan wrong?

(4)SQL Server failover cluster instances are not supported where cluster nodes are domain controllers.
→We don't plan to install failover cluster, so we think that it's not problem. Are we wrong?

(5)SQL Server Setup cannot create security groups or provision SQL Server service accounts 
on a read-only domain controller. In this scenario, Setup will fail.
→Because We have just one server, so it never be a read-only domain controller, so we think that it's not problem. Are we wrong?

Actually, I guess if we clear (1), we can install SQL server 2014 on our domain controller.

Thanks for reading all of sentences.
I hope someone give us answers.

Warmest Regards,
Yoshiaki Fujita, Tokyo, Japan

Comment: I think this is more suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But if hardware is the problem you could think of virtualized servers... Hyper-V for example

Comment: Dear Florian Schmidinger
Thanks for good suggestions.
I am going to put the same question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/
Best Regards,
Yoshiaki